# Change admin payment status back to unpaid for pending order status in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata

When Order status in Woocommerce is changed to *Processing* the payment status is set to **paid**:

But order was accidentally set to **processing** and shouldn't have gotten the status **paid**. Now when we set status to pending again it doesn't remove the text:

> Order #1234 details
>   Payment via Purchase Order. Paid on September 17, 2018 @ 9:18 am

Any idea how to change this text to what is was before status was changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code that will reset (empty) paid date, so it will remove the paid message.

So each time that an order that have a status as "processing", "completed" or "On Hold" is passed back to "Pending" status, the paid date will be emtied.

The code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'reset_order_paid_date', 20, 4 );
function reset_order_paid_date( $order_id, $old_status, $new_status, $order ){
    if ( in_array( $old_status, array('on-hold', 'processing', 'completed') ) && $new_status == 'pending' ) {
        $order->set_date_paid(null);
        $order->save();
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> **To make it effective for your problematic order, run the following code only once**, pasting it on *function.php* child theme's file. Then browse any page of your web site and remove it… 
>   *(where `123` is the order ID that you have to replace by your order ID)*
>
> ```
> $order = wc_get_order( 123 ); // <== HERE set your order number
> $order->set_date_paid(null);
> $order->save();
> ```

---

**Related:** [Set back date paid on paid order statuses change in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55467742/set-back-date-paid-on-paid-order-statuses-change-in-woocommerce/55476651#55476651)

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate it! I only got a error on this line: **$order->set_date_paid(null);** but dont really need that anyway. Thanks.