# Set back date paid on paid order statuses change in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

I WooCommerce, I'm using *"[Change admin payment status back to unpaid for pending order status in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52366455/change-admin-payment-status-back-to-unpaid-for-pending-order-status-in-woocommer/52375231#52375231)"* answer code to reset the paid status of orders when the order status is manually changed in the backend to pending.

So for example, it removes the following if the order status was change from "completed" to "pending": *"Paid on April 2, 2019 @ 5:29 pm"*

Now my problem here is after the order status was set to "pending", I tried to set it again the status to "completed" but it failed to set the date paid or completed date.

I'm using the latest version of Woocommerce Version 5.1.1

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update #1** - To solve this problem try the following:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'pending_reset_order_paid_date', 20, 4 );
function reset_order_paid_date( $order_id, $old_status, $new_status, $order ) {
    // Null paid date
    if ( in_array( $old_status, array('on-hold', 'processing', 'completed') ) && 'pending' === $new_status ) {
        $order->set_date_paid(null);
        $order->update_meta_data( '_reseted_paid_date', true ); // Add a custom meta data flag
        $order->save();
    }
    // Set paid date back when the paid date has been nulled on 'processing' and 'completed' status change
    if( $order->get_meta('_reseted_paid_date' ) && in_array( $new_status, array('pending', 'on-hold') )
        && in_array( $new_status, array('processing', 'completed') ) )
    {
        $order->set_date_paid( current_time( 'timestamp', true ) );
        $order->delete_meta_data( '_reseted_paid_date' ); // Remove the custom meta data flag
        $order->save();
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply sir, but it says "syntax error, unexpected 'in_array' (T_STRING)" with this lines 
if( $order->get_meta('_reseted_paid_date' ) in_array( $new_status, array('pending', 'on-hold') ) ) 
        && in_array( $new_status, array('processing', 'completed') ) ) 
    {

screenshot here https://imgur.com/FJwFab8

Comment: still getting an error sir with your new code with &&, i can't make it work...

"The code snippet you are trying to save produced a fatal error on line 10:
syntax error, unexpected '&&' (T_BOOLEAN_AND)"

can you tell me sir whats wrong in this code....I copied it correctly and paste in it function.php also tried with snippets but failed...do I need change anything in your code..I tried to debug also but im failed sorry...im not good in php sir..help me out..

Comment: Yes sir thank you...works like charm.....this is the code that im lookin for...I will ask again in the future...