# Reset order date paid for a custom order status in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

The following answer code is not working, as I use the custom order status **`pre-ordered`**:

[Change admin payment status back to unpaid for pending order status in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52366455/change-admin-payment-status-back-to-unpaid-for-pending-order-status-in-woocommer/52375231#52375231)

All my products are pre-orders and for that I use a pre-order plugin (from Bright) and the custom payment plugin (from WPRuby), which I have named "Betaal later" (which means "pay later"). Then I have created a custom order status "Pre Ordered", and I have set up this custom status in the custom payment plugin settings, so every order using this payment option, get's the status Pre Ordered.

If the customer makes an order and the only payment option is 'Betaal later', then the order already gets a paid date (the date of the creation of the order) and that's not correct because it is not paid. Can someone help me with this code to work for my situation? It looks like this answer code is not made to work with custom order statuses. Because I have tried to add pre-ordered in the code, but it gives a critical error.

Here is my code attempt:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'reset_order_paid_date', 20, 4 );
function reset_order_paid_date( $order_id, $old_status, $new_status, $order ){
    if ( in_array( $old_status, array('on-hold', 'processing', 'completed', 'pending') ) && $new_status == 'pre-ordered') {
        $order->set_date_paid(null);
        $order->save();
    }
}
```

Here are some screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try the following for your `pre-ordered` custom status:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pre-ordered', 'reset_order_paid_date_for_pre_orders', 900, 2 );
function reset_order_paid_date_for_pre_orders( $order_id, $order ){
    if ( $order->get_date_paid() ) {
        $order->set_date_paid(null);
        $order->save();
    }
}
```

It should work.

---

Addition

You can try to add the following too:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'reset_order_paid_date', 900, 4 );
function reset_order_paid_date( $order_id, $old_status, $new_status, $order ){
    if ( $new_status !== 'completed' && $order->get_date_paid() ) {
        $order->set_date_paid(null);
        $order->save();
    }
}
```

It could solve the issue.

Comment: Thank you for the code. I have added to the functions.php file, but unfortunately it's not working. The pre-order still has the paid date there.

Comment: Update: the code is working. But only for new orders, for that I'm very happy! Thanks. Is it possible to have the paid date removed for the already registered pre-orders ?

Comment: No, by the customer via the website